# Merge regex for password validation

Tags: regex

I need regex for password validation. I have two regexs.

1) String regexOne_must_contain = `"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\\w\\s]).{6,15}$";`
2) String regexTwo_must_not_contain = `"[%,&,+,\\,\\s,\"]";`

I want to combine this regex in one regex to validate password.
The Password length should be of minimum 6 characters, must contains at least one special character(_.!@$*=-?), one upper case, one lower case and one numeric character

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 1):

Change the final part from matching `.` 6-15 times, to matching anything but those prohibited characters, via `[^%&+\\\s"]`.

You also need to properly test for the special characters - put them into a character set. `[^\\w\\s]` isn't enough:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_.!@$*=-?])[^%&+\\\s"]{6,15}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/3eiyMD/1